# Explicity setting port numbers on a UDP client

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, port

I have a UDP Client setup and want to allocate it 3 ports in range [43500,43599] in python. How do I do this? I am using the socket library in python for setting a socket and communicating with a server locally.